# Text search for columnar sum

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a csv file that simplified for here looks something like this:

```
Brett, Spencer, 3, 11, inactive
Bendar, Scott, 4, 8, active
Singh, Jit, 11, 2, active
```

I need to do some kind of grep search (or any other widely available linux utility) that will output all lines in certain columns that add up to a certain value. So if I searched for lines where column 3 and 4 total 13 I would get:

```
Singh, Jit, 11, 2, active
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$3 + $4 == 13 { print }' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Anyway to get it to print out the filenames also? I'm using * for /path/to/file and searching through hundreds of files. { print FILENAME } gets me just the filename but I would like both the output of the filename and the line.

Comment: Add another clause: `FNR==1 { print FILENAME }`

Comment: Or, to make it more like `grep`, do `$3 + $4 == 13 { printf "%s: ", FILENAME; print }`.

Comment: Why two `print` statements rather than `print FILENAME " " $0`?  My suggestion will give you a 'header' block as each file is parsed; @G-Man's (or my reply to it) will prefix the file name to each line.